# Do i need to update the push certificate after 1 year of apple membership

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store, app-store-connect

As of current date [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) gives 99$ account for ios Appstore.
I have an application with push notification services, 
My Apple developer program is auto renewal, So do i need to update the provisioning profile & push service certificate every year with new build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you have to update provision profile and push service certificate every year. **Auto renewal will renew your account not certificate.**

Comment: Also new build required ?

Comment: @Amit no. build is not required

Comment: appreciate your input

Answer (score 5):

Push certificates are used to send notification message from your server(Provider) to Apple Push Notifications services. 
[image]

Application don't know anything about push notification certificates. So if the expiration time is coming you just need to renew push certificates and add then to Provider server. Don't need to renew provision profile and release the new version of the app.

UPDATE:
Added a link to [Apple documentation about Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1)

Comment: appreciate  your input.